# Spring transaction configuration minus Exception (`-Exception`) meaning

Tags: java, spring

I have this configuration in Spring.

What does the `-Exception` mean there (see the `transactionAttributes` property)?

Any official document or tutorial where these properties are well-documented?
I mean where I can find documentation how to define these props in XML Spring configuration files (not as annotations)?

```
    <bean id="proxy_processor"
          class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" 
          lazy-init="default" 
          autowire="default">

        <property name="transactionManager" ref="hibernateTransactionManager"/>
        <property name="target" ref="processor"/>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="process*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception,readOnly</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

[TransactionProxyFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionProxyFactoryBean.html#setTransactionAttributes-java.util.Properties-) documentation for `setTransactionAttributes`. Keys are method name patterns ("process*" matches all methods starting with "process" etc).

And [TransactionAttributeEditor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttributeEditor.html) javadoc

> What does the -Exception mean there (see the transactionAttributes
>   property)?

From the latter page:

> A "+" before an exception name substring indicates that transactions
>   should commit even if this exception is thrown; a "-" that they should
>   roll back.

Transaction propagation types are documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html).

Comment: OK, thanks the `TransactionAttributeEditor` javadoc page was useful.